# Weird behavior of of OptionalFieldEditor

Tags: gwt, gwt-editors

I am using the following editor to support a nullable list:

```
public class NullableListEditor<T, E extends Editor<T>> extends Composite implements 
IsEditor<OptionalFieldEditor< List<T>, ListEditor<T,E> >> {
  private ListEditor<T, E> list = ListEditor.of(new ListEditorSource());
  private final OptionalFieldEditor<List<T>, ListEditor<T, E> > editor = OptionalFieldEditor.of(list);
…
}
public class NullableAListEditor  extends NullableListEditor<A, AEditor> {..}
public class NullableBListEditor  extends NullableListEditor<B, BEditor> {..}
```

If I create two instances, say first create NullableAListEditor  and then NullableBListEditor,  NullableAListEditor will work fine but NullableBListEditor will fail complaining that BEditor cannot be cast to AEditor.  (If I create B then A, A will fail for the similar reason.)
I debugged into it and it seemed to be a problem in AbstractEditorDelegate.java:
http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/releases/2.4/user/src/com/google/gwt/editor/client/impl/AbstractEditorDelegate.java?r=10474
in line 75, for NullableBListEditor , the object type returned by  createComposedDelegate()is the same as that of NullableAListEditor. It seemed like that the type won’t change anymore after the creation of the first editor (NullableAListEditor),  but I couldn’t figure out why.

The detailed errors:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: ..editor.B.BEditor cannot be cast to
...editor.A.AEditor
at ..editor.A.AEditor_SimpleBeanEditorDelegate.setEditor(AEditor_SimpleBeanEditorDelegate.java:6)
    at com.google.gwt.editor.client.impl.AbstractEditorDelegate.initialize(AbstractEditorDelegate.java:200)
    at com.google.gwt.editor.client.impl.AbstractEditorDelegate.addSubDelegate(AbstractEditorDelegate.java:156)
    at com.google.gwt.editor.client.impl.AbstractEditorDelegate$Chain.attach(AbstractEditorDelegate.java:78)
    at com.google.gwt.editor.client.adapters.ListEditorWrapper.attach(ListEditorWrapper.java:95)
    at com.google.gwt.editor.client.adapters.ListEditor.setValue(ListEditor.java:164)
    at com.google.gwt.editor.client.adapters.ListEditor.setValue(ListEditor.java:1)
    at com.google.gwt.editor.client.impl.Refresher.visit(Refresher.java:40)
    at com.google.gwt.editor.client.impl.Initializer.visit(Initializer.java:49)
    at com.google.gwt.editor.client.impl.AbstractEditorContext.traverse(AbstractEditorContext.java:128)
    at com.google.gwt.editor.client.impl.AbstractEditorDelegate$Chain.traverse(AbstractEditorDelegate.java:100)
    at com.google.gwt.editor.client.impl.AbstractEditorDelegate$Chain.attach(AbstractEditorDelegate.java:83)
    at com.google.gwt.editor.client.adapters.OptionalFieldEditor.setValue(OptionalFieldEditor.java:113)
    at com.google.gwt.editor.client.impl.Refresher.visit(Refresher.java:40)
    at com.google.gwt.editor.client.impl.Initializer.visit(Initializer.java:49)
    at com.google.gwt.editor.client.impl.AbstractEditorContext.traverse(AbstractEditorContext.java:128)
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks a lot,
-Jeff

Answer (score 0):

You're *simply* running into [issue 6016](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6016). It's fixed in GWT 2.5.0-rc1.

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for the answer. I downloaded GWT 2.5.0-rc1 and tried again, but the issue is still happening. It might be a specific problem for OptionalFieldEditor or CompositeEditor. Any chance that the issue was not fixed for them? I have been blocked by this issue. Thanks a lot! -Jeff

Comment: Is the stacktrace the same? If not, would you mind posting it somewhere? (updating the Q here, using PasteBin or GitHub Gists, or in a comment to issue 6016). I suspect it could be due to the use of type variables in the subeditor's parameterization.

Comment: Yes, the stacktrace is the same. Also please check my update with codes and errors: "To isolate the problem, I created two independent Editors that implements OptionalFieldEditor, but still got the same errors..."

Comment: OK, first time I ever see this issue. Would you mind filing an issue at http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/entry ?

Comment: Filed: code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7625  Since it's a blocking issue for me, I am wondering do you know normally how long it takes for this kind of issue to be fixed? Need to decide if I should wait or seek other ways.  Thanks!

Comment: It'll probably take a few months before it ships in a release. As a workaround maybe you could create subclasses of OptionalFieldEditor to disambiguate them (just a shoot in the dark here, I'd have to actually debug the issue first)

Comment: Hi Thomas, could you be more specific on the workaround? It's my first time using GWT so I am not that familiar with it. Would it be something like: public class ListEditorA implements IsEditor<OptionalFieldEditorA>{}; public class ListEditorB implements IsEditor<OptionalFieldEditorB>{}? Which methods shall I override in the subclasses(OptionalFieldEditorA and OptionalFieldEditoB) of OptionalFieldEditor?   Thanks a lot!

Comment: Something along the lines of `class OptionalFieldEditorA extends OptionalFieldEditor<List<A>, ListEditor<A, AEditor>> { }`, you don't need to override any method, just provide a specific type without generics (see issue 6016)

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I will try it when I get a chance. Also, I got a related question about implement a NullablesetEditor on top of NullableListEdito, I am wondering could you give any hint on that: [NullableSetEditor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190355/implement-nullableseteditor-by-wrapping-a-nullalblelisteditor)