# Implement NullableSetEditor by wrapping a NullalbleListEditor

Tags: gwt, gwt-editors

I have a working NullableStringListEditor implementation:

```
public class NullableStringListEditor extends Composite implements IsEditor<OptionalFieldEditor< List<String>, ListEditor<String, StringEditor> >> {...}
```

Now, I am building a NullableStringSetEditor by wrapping it:

```
public class NullableStringSetEditor extends Composite implements ValueAwareEditor<Set<String>>, LeafValueEditor<Set<String>> {
private NullableStringListEditor wrappedEditor = new NullableStringListEditor();

    @Override
    public void setValue(Set<String> values) {
        List<String> list = wrappedEditor.asEditor().getValue();
        some null checking... 
        list.clear();
        list.addAll(values);
        wrappedEditor.asEditor().setValue(list); // will call setValue of OptionalFieldEditor from here
    }
}
```

Error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null at com.google.gwt.editor.client.adapters.OptionalFieldEditor.setValue(OptionalFieldEditor.java:113)
```

line 113: chain.attach(value, subEditor);
it seems like chain is always null.

Am I doing something wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If `NullableStringSetEditor` is a `LeafvalueEditor`, then `wrappedEditor` will be ignored by the Editor framework generator, and thus won't be initialized and populated.

You might want to follow the `OptionaEditor` pattern by having your editor be a `CompositeEditor` (in addition to being a `LeafValueEditor`)

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I am very close now, the only issue now is that values are not updated after flush(). I posed the codes as a new response below. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Hi Thomas, unfortunately I still can't figure out how to make update works for NullableStringSetEditor. No value was updated after flush() although values contained in the wrappedEditor were changed. Do you have any clue? Thanks a lot!